# Error resolving template [registration], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, thymeleaf, tomcat9

I'm learning Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and Spring Data JPA. I've created a sample project for myself, where i could learn all those stuff. I dont ask many questions here, because usually it is some dumb mistake and I get hate for that. However, I am so stuck at this one error, that I have no other choice.

This is my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nteER.png)

This is configuration class (I excluded imports for simplicity):

```
package com.edemko.warehousemanager;

public class WarehouseManagerConfig {

@Autowired    
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean
public ViewResolver thymeleafResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());        
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

    return templateEngine;
}

 }
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

@GetMapping("registration")
public String getRegistration(@ModelAttribute ("registration") Registration registration) {        
    return "registration";
}

 }
```

Whole application can be seen [here](https://github.com/Hyperxion/warehouse-manager). I also get warning: Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration). But it is there, as you can see in project structure picture.

index.html is loading correctly, no problem. When I click on link for registration, whitelabel error page. Any tips are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is no need for all that configuration. You can have a look at [the example code of my book](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources) to see how to get started with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. [Chapter 3](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources/tree/main/chapter03) has the simplest example.

Comment: But what is wrong with this configuration? It is going to be complex project and I want to keet this file structure, it is more kind of standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I moved registration.html into templates forlder, both "/templates/ folder cannot be found" and internal server error disappeard and works correctly,even thou without custom file location